# How does a push pull CMOS output drive a pin LOW

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, resistors, push-pull

Can someone tell me how does a push pull CMOS output drive a pin low?

I am having a microcontroller with push pull CMOS output.

For high drive, the TOP MOSFET is turned ON and drives the line high. But when driving Low, even if the bottom MOSFET is ON, there is no pull-up resistor on the line to make line go low?

What if there's a pull-down resistor on the other side of the CMOS output? How will the microcontroller drive the push pull CMOS output to low?

Comment: *there is no pull-up resistor on the line to make line go low?* How can a **pull up** resistor pull a line **low**? Also there is no need for a (pulldown) resistor as the bottom (NMOS) transistor will already pull the line low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this using simple switches rather than semiconductors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7eUkY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Various options.*

- (a) Both switches are open. This is known as a tri-state output as it can be high, low or open. If OUT should not be undefined then a pull-up or pull-down resistor should be added.
- (b) SW3 is closed so OUT is connected to V+ and is pulled high very strongly.
- (c) SW6 is closed so OUT is connected to GND. Output is low.
- (d) SW8 is closed pulling OUT low. R1 is bringing nothing to the party other than wasting energy when OUT is high.
- (e) In this case there is no low-side switch so when SW9 is open R2 pulls OUT low and provides a defined logic level the the following stage.

> For high drive, the TOP MOSFET is turned ON and drives the line high. But when driving Low, even if the bottom MOSFET is ON, there is no pull-up resistor on the line to make line go low?

A pull-up resistor, as the name suggests, pulls the line high. Adding a pull-up resistor would not help the line go low.

> What if there's a pull-down resistor on the other side of the CMOS output? How will the microcontroller drive the push pull CMOS output to low?

See (d) or (e).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you tell me how does the SDO pin work in this Motor Driver IC? Like, the SDO pin is a push pull output. In that case, should the pin connected to the microcontroller have an internal pull-down resistor? I have connected the Motor Driver to the Microcontroller and trying to find the IO Logic Compatibility. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8889-q1.pdf?ts=1621230878657&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Since it has a push-pull output (See section 7.2) no pull-up or pull-down is required and none is provided according to 7.2. It works like my Figure 1b and 1c.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, I can configure my microcontroller pin just as Input with no internal pull-up and pull-down right?

Comment: But for logic compatibility check, what would the SDO high Output value be and what would the SDO low Output value be? How to find this out?

Comment: 7.2 shows you that it can switch between VSDO and GND. Page 4 tells you that you connect VSDO to a 3.3 V or 5 V supply depending on the operating voltage of the microcontroller you are working with.

Comment: Yes. My Microcontroller Vih is 0.7*3.3V = 2.31V & Vil = 0.3*3.3V = 0.99V. And the VSDO is connected to 3.3V. In this case, can you tell me how to calculated the Voh and Vol of the SDO pin?

Comment: Table 6.5 gives you the effective pull-up and pull-down resistance of the transistors at 5 mA. You won't be pulling or pushing anything like that much current. It will switch fine for your application.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I saw that table. But I was not sure, on how that much current would reflect on the SDO lines. But what would be the voltage or say, what would be the current value in my case?

Comment: Sorry to trouble with too many questions in the comments. Still confused

Comment: Look at the specifications for the input to your microcontroller. I think we're going way beyond your original question now so if you have further questions then open a new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124377/discussion-between-newbie-and-transistor).

Comment: If the datasheet, they have given 5mA current. But in my application, how is the current determined? Do I need to enable an internal pull down resistor n the microcontroller?

Comment: Can you not see that a push-pull output does not require resistors. The switches do the pulling and pushing. In the datasheet they tell you what the voltage will be if you push or pull 5 mA. You're feeding a GPIO with an input resistance probably > 1 MΩ so it will draw 5 μA. There is no problem to be solved. As I said already, this conversation has deviated too far from your original question so I won't be replying to further comments on this post. Ask a new question if you're still confused and reference this one if it helps.